# Averaging over specific values in a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
example <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep(101, 4), rep(102,4)),
  condition = c(rep(c('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),2)),
  value = c(1,1,4,5,1,1,4,5)
)
```

I want to create a new dataframe consisting only of 2 values in `condition`: aggregate and test4. 'aggregate' will be an average of values across condition 'test1', 'test2' and 'test3' by `subject`. This is what the example solution looks like:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  subject = c(101, 102, 101, 102),
  condition = c("aggregate", 'test4', 'aggregate', 'test4'),
  value = c(2,5,2,5)
)
```

How may I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Since you got the dplyr tag I assume thats what you want: Create overwrite 'condition' with a new variabel that aggregates to "aggregate" or "test4", then use `group_by'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

example |>
  mutate(condition = ifelse(condition == "test4", "test4", "aggregate")) |>
  summarize(value = mean(value), .by = c(subject, condition))

#   subject condition value
# 1     101 aggregate     2
# 2     101     test4     5
# 3     102 aggregate     2
# 4     102     test4     5
```